# Possibilty to use Unicode Blocks (\p{InBasic_Latin}) in regex built-in of Python 3.7 to match canonical equivalence

Tags: python, regex, unicode

In order to write a shorter regex expression and precise one, I want to know the possibility to use unicode blocks as shown [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#prop).

The problem when I try to use `'\p{InBasic_Latin}'` with regex built-in is the returned error `re.error: bad escape \p at position ...`

Is it possible to use unicode blocks with python 3.7's regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python 3.7 does not support Unicode Properties.

But a equivalent of `\p{InBasic_Latin}` should be `[\u0000-\u007F]`